# Why Javascript replace is not working in this case

Tags: javascript

I have got a string with #! and i want to replace the #! with empty .

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var uri =  'ghgfhf'
   if (uri.indexOf("#") > 0) {
    var clean_uri =  removeURLParameter(uri);
    console.log(clean_uri);
}
});

function removeURLParameter(url) {
url = url.replace(/!#/,'');
return url;
}
```

Could you please let me know how to replace the #! with empty ('')

Comment: I can see no "!#" in your URL, just "#!", but your regex says "!#"

Comment: `url = url.replace('#!','');` - http://jsfiddle.net/52aK9/1589/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"!#"` should be `"#!"`

```
function removeURLParameter(url) {
    url = url.replace(/#!/,'');
    return url;
}
```

See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52aK9/1588/)